# How should I organize web apps in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

Say I make a web app for my main page and publish it to wwwroot (assuming this is the default website). Do I publish other web apps by nesting them within wwwroot. Something like wwwroot/webapp1 for example? This seems somewhat messy to me, so I'm not quite sure if it's the correct way of doing it. Therefore, I'm wondering how the rest of you would organize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally do not put applications inside of other applications when using IIS. This is because I do MVC applications that can take over all the routing and it'd be really annoying to host applications in the folders inside. Even if you are not doing MVC applications, I would still avoid doing it, and instead make multiple websites that listen on different host headers or ports. If you need to have applications nested like that I would use a reverse proxy like HAProxy and setup routing there instead.

Comment: Don't necessarily need to nest them, but would there be any other way to do something like http://*.com and then http://*.com/webapp1? Or do people not generally do it like this and just create another website?